How to prove that submodules of $L = b(n,F)$ indecomposable
Let $F$ be a field,$L = b(n, F)$ and $V = F^n$. Let $e_1, ..., e_n$ be the standard basis of $F^n$. Define $W_r = Span\{e_1,...,e_r\}$, with $1 \leq r \leq n$. It can be proved that $W_r$ a submodule of $V$.
How do I deduce that each $W_r$ is indecomposable?
Intuitively, for strictly upper triangular matrices, for matrix elements on the top right corner, those cannot get captured in any submodule. In other words, there is no $U$ or $W$ to achieve $V = U \oplus W$, thus $V$ cannot be decomposed. But I am not sure if this reasoning is sufficient for a proof...
This is part of exercise 7.6(iii) of book Introduction to Lie Algebras by Karin Erdmann and Mark J. Wildon. And this is not for assignment, only for reading.

Generally, a module $M$ is decomposable iff $\text{End}(M)$ contains a nontrivial idempotent (corresponding to a projection onto a direct summand). So you can show that $M$ is indecomposable by calculating the endomorphism ring and showing that it has no nontrivial idempotents.

I figured it out later myself. Notice that $b(n, F)$ is strictly upper triangular matrix in the notation of this book. The key lies in the first sentence of question (iii) of 7.6: "Show that every non-zero submodule of V is equal to one of the $W_r$."
This can be proven as such:
Assume that a submodule $W$ do not contain $e_1$. Since $\exists x \in b(n, F)$, such that $x(0, i) \neq 0$. Then if $e_i \in W$, $x \cdot w = e_1$. This is in conflict with the assumption that $e_1 \notin W$.    $\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\square$
Thus submodules must contain all previous standard basis by induction.
Since all submodules $W_r$'s overlap, V is not completely reducible as an L-module.
